# ASP.NET Event OnAuthenticationFailed?

Tags: asp.net

Is there an event that gets fired right after ASP.NET authentication has failed to identify the user? I need to trigger an alarm every time that happens. Don't offer to implement custom membership provider nor to do it from the Login form's controller. I'm looking for native ASP.NET pipeline event. HttpApplication has two events: one for **before** Authentication and one **after**, but nothing for **failure**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remeber, yes:
Have a close look at the logging capabilites of the HealthMonitoring section. It is not only possible to log errors, but also events such as successfull logins or failed login.

Have a look at http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/logging-error-details-with-asp-net-health-monitoring-cs

I guess `eventName="Failure Audits"` is the way to go